# How to pass custom variables to the PayPal recurring payments

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

My task is to create a PayPal recurring payments on my website. This can be done using PayPal API.

If you want to create recurring payments, you first have to create a recurring profile in the PayPal account of the buyer.  You can create recurring by calling Paypal API `createRecurringPayment` method. What you should do before this call you can read [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/).

Let's say that every month we want charge user for 10$. As per PayPal documentation, my IPN listener every moth will be notified about this transaction and this is fine. But the problem is that I have to pass custom values to my IPN lister (user ID) to identify the user and then to extend it's subscription. How to pass the custom variables when recurring payment happens automatically?

Please can someone help me with this?

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value='<?php echo json_encode(array('user_id' => $user_id, 'product' => 'property-advert')) ?>' />
```

Comment: Hi RAJESH, this can be useful when you use classic approach when using hidden fields. I need something totally different.

Comment: Hi Mr. M, Alright this is different. But there could be one way. You can save the profile id in table, and at IPN hits you can use then you can find that profile id in your table. I think GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails could be used for this.